# How to select pie chart slice by default in Charts library

Tags: ios, swift, charts, pie-chart, ios-charts

Am using Pie chart in, [Charts ios library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). I want to know, how can i select first slice by default when it Pie chart loads.

I found this `chartView.highlightValue(x: 45, dataSetIndex: 0)`. But this code is not working.

My pie chart has two slices with `PieChartDataEntry`. I want first one to be selected by default.

```
let entries = (0..<count).map { (i) -> PieChartDataEntry in
            if i == 0 {
                return PieChartDataEntry(value: 45,
                                         label: "")
            } else {
                return PieChartDataEntry(value: 55,
                                         label: "")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first slice to be selected, set the `x` to be `0`. Note that `x` here is the `index` of your data and `dataSetIndex` is always `0` for `PieCharts`

```
chartView.highlightValue(x: 0, dataSetIndex: 0)
```

Comment: Your code is working. Is there a way to make outer shadow on selected Slice?